# Ordering a maths equation into two, equal columns

Tags: math-mode, formatting, grid-typesetting

This question is currently taking up a bit too much space. I was wondering if it is possible to split **ONLY** the solution of this maths equation, not anything above or below it, into two equal sides which will take up half the space? Below is the picture of my current solution and there is also an another photo of what I want it somehow to look like.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newcommand\ud{\,\mathrm{d}} % shortcuts for d, du, dv, dx, dy 
\newcommand\udu{\ud\,u}
\newcommand\udv{\ud\,v}
\newcommand\udx{\ud\,x}
\newcommand\udy{\ud\,y}
 \begin{document}
    \subsubsection{Examples}
\begin{description}
\item [Example 1]
Find $\frac{\udy}{\udx}$ for $x=\mathrm{e}^{2y+1}$
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task in terms of $y$.
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
x & =\mathrm{e}^{2y+1} \\
\frac{\udx}{\udy} & =  2{e}^{2y+1} \\
\frac{\udy}{\udx} & = \frac{1} {2{e}^{2y+1}}
\end{split}
\end{align*}
\task in terms of $x$.
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
x & = \mathrm{e}^{2y+1}\text{\space\space , \space}x>0 \\
\log_{\mathrm{e}}^(x) & = 2y+1 \\
2y & = \log_{\mathrm{e}}^(x)-1 \\
y & = \frac{1}{2}\log_{\mathrm{e}}^(x)-\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{\udy}{\udx} & = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{x} \\
\frac{\udy}{\udx} & = \frac{1}{2x}
\end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{tasks}
\item [Example 2]
Find the equations of tangents to the curve with equation $x=2-3y^2$ at the points where $x=-1$.
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
 \text{When\space} x & =-1\text{ , }\\
-1 & =2-3y^2 \\
3y^2 & =3 \\
y^2 & =1 \\
y & =\pm1 \\
x & =2-3y^2 \\
\therefore \frac{\udx}{\udy} & =-6y \\
\frac{\udy}{\udx} & =\frac{1}{-6y} \\
\text{When\space }y=-1 & \text{ , }\frac{\udy}{\udx}=\frac{1}{6} \\
\text{When\space }y=1 & \text{ , }\frac{\udy}{\udx}=-\frac{1}{6} 
\end{split}
\end{align*}
The equation of the tangent at $(-1, -1)$ with gradient $\frac{1}{6}$: \\
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
y-(-1) & =\frac{1}{6}(x-(-1)) \\
y & =\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{1}{6}-1 \\
y & =\frac{1}{6}x-\frac{5}{6} 
\end{split}
\end{align*}
The equation of the tangent at $(-1, 1)$ with gradient $-\frac{1}{6}$: \\
\begin{align*}
\begin{split}
y-1 & =-\frac{1}{6}(x-(-1)) \\
y & =-\frac{1}{6}x-\frac{1}{6}+1 \\
y & =-\frac{1}{6}x+\frac{5}{6} 
\end{split}
\end{align*}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: What it looks like currently]
[image: What I want my page to look like]

Comment: Have you tried the `multicol` package?

Comment: @azetina Yes - it seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: Remove all the `\,` in the definition related to `\ud`; they are wrong.